# Hiding Paypal section of WooCommerce's Braintree Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

I am using a [payments plugin by WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-gateway-paypal-powered-by-braintree/), which shows both options to checkout via credit card and paypal. The PayPal one keeps giving me issues. So I would like to hide the PayPal section until the plugin can be fixed. Does anyone know how I can do that?

[image: Checkout Screenshot Image]

Answer (score 0):

There should be an option under **WooCommerce > Settings > Checkout > PayPal Powered by Braintree** to enabled or disable PayPal checkout. If you untick the box **Enable PayPal Powered by Braintree** the PayPal option should no longer show up. You can find more information about configuring this plugin in the [setup docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-gateway-paypal-powered-by-braintree/#section-3).

Comment: Thanks @natdempk. If I untick the Enable PayPal Powered by Braintree, it would disable the entire plugin (including the Credit Card portion). What I'm hoping to do is disable just the PayPal portion & still keep the credit card part (which is powered by the same plugin).